# UIImage sliding indicator size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I have 2 `UIImage`'s one on top of another and the top one slides and reveals the coloured one. The issue is that I want the indicator (purple line, which is a view) to indicate in the left side only by the end of the image (image`s background is clear).

What I want is to resize that purple line so it wold be visible in the left side and on the image but not on the right side, as it is now.

Any ideas of what I can try ? I have no idea where to start, thank you!

What I did so far:

[image: a]
what I want:
[image: a]

Comment: Ther result of your work looks very nice. Please paste your code here

Comment: It is very unclear what your problem is as your question is written. What is your app doing now? How is it not working? What do you mean "indicate in the right side only"?

Comment: I think I know what he wants: He want to remove colors from given image (like that girl) up to purple line. The line can be moved up and down. Am I correct @edo? If so please improve your question.

Comment: now the view shows the grey image and slides up to show the coloured image ... what I want is to resize that purple line so it wold be visible in the left side and on the image but not on the right side, as it is now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to implement programmatically using `CGImageCreateWithMask`, but it is very hard. Also such solution will be not very fast, if you want to do it in real time.

I offer next solution: create 3-d image, as shown below. That picture must be a white mask, which will limit your line. Place that picture above pic 1 and 2. Pink line should also be placed below that picture.

[image: girl]

Sorry, if I wrote something unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks kelin, the idea that you gave me was interesting, but I did not had time for that, so I found another way of doing this. I used a third image for the mask witch is an image with the lady`s shape cut off and a white background but only in the right side of the picture (the left half side image and lady shape is transparent), and the line crosses on top of the pictures shown previously and under the image I added with mask... 
Simple and efficient, and it uses way less memory for a real time displaying with an animation .

Comment: It is exactly what I wanted to propose :) Good job anyway.